# How to share dependencies in a Modularized Android App

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, clean-architecture, android-architecture

I have an Android project which is architectured in a Modularized way. I have modularized the projects by dividing their source code between multiple Gradle modules, following the [clean Architecture](https://antonioleiva.com/clean-architecture-android/).

Here is the structure of the App.

[image]

The top module in this hierarchy, `App` is the one that no other module depends upon, is the main module of your application. The lower level modules `domain` and `data` do not depend on the `App` module, where the `App` module includes the `data` and `domain` modules. I have added the below code in the build.gradle of the `app` module

```
    implementation project(':domain')
    api project(':data')
```

Now, I'm having some issues with maintaining dependencies across each module. Since each of them is an individual android module, each of them having its own `build.gradle`. The `App` module can use classes in the `data` and `domain` modules. But, I have some general purpose classes, (Such as some annotations, Utilities, Broadcast classes, Dagger scopes etc) which I want to make use in all the modules. But these are the issues I'm facing

> - Since these classes are contained in the main module `app`, I cannot
>     access these in my `data` and `domain`, because those modules do not
>     depend on the higher layer `app`
> - Any libraries I'm using in all the layers (eg: RxJava) needs to be
>     included in the `build.gradle` of each module

As a solution for this I thought of adding one more android module, say `common` which will be containing all my general purpose classes as well as the libraries which I use in all the modules.

All my other modules `app`, `domain` and `data` will be having this module as a dependency.

```
implementation project(':common')
```

So, any global libraries and classes will be added to this module and each of the individual modules will have only module-specific classes.

Is that a good approach? Or is there any way to solve this issue efficiently?

Comment: demodularize your app? modularization only helps large teams work together efficiently.most apps don't really need it. if you're having trouble and are a single dev/small team, there is no point maintaining "clean-architecture" aside from a learning experience. is this just for learning or are you going to be putting this in production?

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan It's a production App where the size is bit large. So, we wanted to have some clear seperation across modules

Comment: how does modularization help with the large size requirements? sounds like you're over-engineering

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan I wanted to give a try to [this](https://proandroiddev.com/intro-to-app-modularization-42411e4c421e). Forget whether its over engineering or not, but what would be an ideal solution for the above problems, if we ever go for such a modularization

Answer (score 20):

We recently encountered this problem, as we transitioned to a multi-module project for reuse, build time optimisation (unchanged modules aren't recompiled), etc. Your core goal is to make your `app` module as small as possible, as it will be recompiled every time.

We used a few general principles, which may help you:

- A common `base-ui` module contains the primary `strings.xml`, `styles.xml` etc.
- Other front-end modules (`profile`, `dashboard`, etc) implement this `base-ui` module.
- Libraries that will be used in *all* user-facing modules are included in `base-ui`, as an `api` instead of `implementation`.
- Libraries that are only used in *some* modules are added as dependencies only in those modules.
- The project makes extensive use of data syncing etc too, so there are also `base-data`, `dashboard-data` etc modules, following the same logic.
- The `dashboard` feature module depends on `dashboard-data`.
- The `app` module depends only on feature modules, `dashboard`, `profile`, etc.

I strongly suggest sketching out your module dependency flow beforehand, we ended up with ~15 or so modules, all strictly organised. In your case, you mentioned it's already quite a large app, so I imagine `app` needs feature modules pulled out of it, as does `domain`. Remember, small modules = less code to be recompiled!

We encountered some issues with making sure the same version (`buildType`, `flavors`) of the app was used across all submodules. Essentially, all submodules have to have the same `flavor`s and `buildType`s defined as the `app` module.

On the other side of the coin, multi module development does really make you think about dependencies, and enforces strict separation between features. You're likely to run into a few unexpected problems that you've never considered before. For example, something as simple as displaying the app's version [suddenly complicates](https://blog.jakelee.co.uk/how-to-display-app-version-inside-a-submodule/) (disclaimer: my article).

[This article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-modularisation-affects-build-time-of-an-android-application-43a984ce9968) also helped us decide on our approach. The article you linked also seems to be an excellent resource, I wish it had existed when we'd transitioned!

After comment discussion, here's an example diagram (with unfortunate untidiness, but enough to illustrate the concept. Note that distinguishing between `api` and `implementation` would be a good next step):
[image: module dependency diagram]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Your approach sounds good. Also, I have some more queries on that. As per my understanding, the `base-ui` layer is the one which is closer to the framework. Does this layer act as a driver module for your dependency injection logic? We are using dagger2 for DI. So, the dependency resolution code, for all the sub modules,  can exist in this layer? Which acts as a driver module for all other modules?

Comment: One issue we faced durig the architecture was, We wanted to keep the interaction only between the releavant modules. For example, 
We need to have `app` -> `domain` -> `data` layer interation in such a way that, `app` is communicating to `domain` layer only, but not directly to the inner layer  `data`. So, we are restricting access of any `data` layer classes inside `app` module, since `domain` layer is the one who is directly delaling with `data`. 
It is possible to restrict this access , if we add the `data` module to `domain` module as gradle `implementation`.

Comment: But, since the top layer `app` (in your structure it can be `base-ui`) is the one who manages the DI logic, which means dagger exists in `app` layer and needs 
to have access to some of the classes in `data` layer to resolve the dependency graph. This forces us to add the `data` module either directly to `app` module, or
as `api` to `domain` module, inorder to get access to `data` module. But adding it will allow access to any class in the `data` layer directly from `app` layer. Is that a good approach to do so? 
Or should the DI code exist in some other dedicated module?

Comment: We didn't use DI, so I can't speak specifically. In general though, if you do go for smaller modules as mentioned, you avoid large portions of the app being able to access base modules they don't need. I think you're perhaps misunderstanding somewhat re: `app`, that is always the top layer. `base-ui` is the bottom. `dashboard` is in between. I could draw a diagram if it would help?

Comment: **_I could draw a diagram if it would help_** It would be very helpful

Comment: [Here](https://i.imgur.com/ZrEXZaS.png). It's a little outdated though, and I haven't distinguished between `api` and `implementation`. It should be enough to explain my thoughts though!